# AWS SQS -> Lamda connection: determine how many times an event has fired inside lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda that:

- receives an event from SQS
- sends call to third-party service
- on failure records a Rollbar
  SQS will retry event 3 times then send to DLQ

The problem is that it fails quite often but succeeds on retry. It triggers Rollbar that I have to go and check by hand.

I wondered if there was a way to record a Rollbar ONLY if this is the last of 3 retries and it will go to DLQ now.

There is *ApproximateReceiveCount* that seems to work but I'm concerned about it having *Approximate* in its name

1. Is *ApproximateReceiveCount* reliable way to determine if the lambda is going to DLQ next?
2. Is there any other fast and reliable way to implement that?

This is an example of how I thought of doing that

```py
@rollbar.lambda_function
def handler(event, context):
    approximate_receive_count = event['Records'][0]['attributes']['ApproximateReceiveCount']

    
    if int(approximate_receive_count) < MAX_RECEIVE_COUNT:
        raise Exception("Simulate transient server failure")
    
    if int(approximate_receive_count) >= MAX_RECEIVE_COUNT:
        raise Exception('Simulate final failure')

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Lambda function executed successfully.'})
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean "rollback", or are you using the [Rollbar](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=f2e5067e-9b16-40db-b53d-63e5403d5118) product?

Comment: Rollbar product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's called `ApproximateReceiveCount` because SQS does not guarantee only-once delivery and the same message could be in some edge cases picked up by two lambdas at the same time (in which case both would have the same value for `ApproximateReceiveCount`. If you really cannot tolerate these cases then you can't use `ApproximateReceiveCount` attribute. For precise solution, you could:

1. Store counts in an external DB, like DynamoDB, keyed by message ID or some other unique ID.
2. Rely on messages being in DLQ instead. Not sure how that integrates with Rollbar, as I haven't used that, but you can easily set up a DLQ alarm in CloudWatch and wire that to external system or even create another lambda that processes DLQ messages and performs some custom processing that you need

Comment: Thank you! The question is then - let's say retry count is 3 (after 3rd attempt it will go to DLQ) - ApproximateReceiveCount is 2 and it is sent to two lambdas at the same time, both see it as 2 and both fail. Will it go to DLQ now even though no lambda ever saw it with ApproximateReceiveCount equal 3?

Comment: @Artem - I don't think that behavior is explicitly documented by AWS, but my guess is that it would make another attempt where the count would be 3, because count is tracked by SQS, not by Lambda.